# Modifying variables in a closure

Tags: javascript, closures

My focus in this question is making HTML5 games. The aim is to help reduce/prevent cheating.

If a variable in global scope held the score, for example `var score = 0`, then it's really easy to cheat just by running `javascript:void(score = 9999999999);`.

But if I had something more like this:

```
(function() {
    var score = 0;
    // game logic here
})();
```

Is `score` accessible by anything outside the closure? Is there any way for the player to modify it and thus falsify their points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of that closure, `score` does not exist (or at least, *that* `score` doesn't).

If you want to prevent cheaters, the only real way when the whole game runs on the client side is to recreate the game environment and user input on the server and validate that.

Otherwise, anyone can modify your client side code and send what they wish to your server.

Comment: I know that completely preventing cheating is pretty much impossible, but with a combination of proper closures, encrypting client-server communication and obfuscating the code, I can hope to at least significantly reduce it.

Thanks for confirming the answer for me.

Comment: @Kolink No worries. I love HTML5 games, show me your game when it's done :)

Answer (score 4):

Everything that happens on the client side is 'hackable', because you simply do not have any control over it. The only real way to prevent this is using serverside validation (e.g. AJAX calls).

> Is score accessible by anything outside the closure?

No it isn't.

> Is there any way for the player to modify it and thus falsify their points?

Yup. See my first statement.